# AngularJS bind value after initialization

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, dynamic-binding

I have a dynamic HTML page. One element (textarea) is generated via php (third party library) and I can't set ng-model for it. Can I setup ng-model for textarea after initialization, maybe jQuery callback or something similar.

Comment: any specific reason for generating the element through php?

Comment: to add on to what Aravind said: there's probably a way to cobble something together, but taking the textarea out of php's hands and implementing the whole frontend in angular will save you a lot of pain

Comment: have you tried calling $compile, after adding ng-model

Comment: I'm looking for a solution how to resolve this issue. First look told me I can't modify this php callback (it's generated tinyMCE editor), but maybe I wrong.

Comment: You guess I should call $compile for whole page after markup is done? Before that I should also add ng-model attribute to my textarea I think.

Comment: I found a solution. I use this code ob_start(); ob_get_contents(); and ob_end_clean();, than I modify textarea with my attributes with ng-model. Works good as I see.